# what is the meaning of jQuery selector carry a second parameter?

Tags: jquery

When I read the book, I found that I can't understand this

```
$("span.task-name",$task).text(taskName);
```

`task-name` is the class for span tag

Can some one help me with that? 
What is the exact meaning of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter is for context: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1

It is similar to `.find()`, where it takes a jquery selection and tries to refine it with a new selector. For example, if you wanted to select `span.span1` within `#div1`, you would do:

```
$("span.span1", "#div1");
```

This is identical to:

```
$("#div1 span.span1");
```

Between the two, there is really only a small difference in performance, but no difference in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The main jQuery function has a few distinct signatures, the one you're showing here is a context:

```js
$( ".foo", "#bar" ); // Same as $( "#bar .foo" ), or $( "#bar" ).find( ".foo" );
```

This will find instances of `.foo` *within* `#bar`. Alternatively, you can pass in an object with attributes (and more) that are intended for a freshly created element:

```js
$( "<div></div>", { html: "<b>Hi</b>" } ); // $( "<div></div>" ).html( "<b>Hi</b>" );
```

This is similar to calling the `$.fn.html` method on a newly-created `DIV` element.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery documentation:

> Selector Context
>
> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting
>   at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for
>   the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is the context. There's a example: let's say you have already selected #div, and you want to select spans inside of div.

You'll do it like that:

```
var spans = $('#div').find('span');
```

Instead of finding through `.find()` you can use second argument of jQuery():

```
var div = $('#div');
var spans = $('span', div);
```

That's way, you specifiying context for jQuery function, hope that helped to understand. :)